SSH Error：Permission denied, please try again
Recently, I installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and found that it worked the first time I logged in, but then it didn't!
I did the following configurations, but the problem is not solved
sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssd_config
Port 22
PermitRootLogon yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow openssh

Here is the error message
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@4.4.55.32's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.

So, I'm wanted to find how to handle it. Thanks

The root account in Ubuntu is disabled by default - have you actually set a root password?

Yes, I have set the root password with the command sudo passwd root. That's why I'm confused about the mechanism here, it's clear that the first time I logged in with ssh root@server-ip it worked, but the second time and after that with the password it didn't work!
